# LibreOffice writer: Adding bookmarks

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, bookmarks

I want to fill out the "Structure/Index" panel that is visible when viewing PDFs but I am not sure how to work this out in LibreOffice writer. In picture #1 the bookmarks I want to add are marked by red arrows. I used the menu `Insert -> Bookmarks...` but these do not show up in PDF, in picture #2.

[image]
[image]

Comment: According to the documentation, it *should* work by inserting **index marks**: Menu `Insert` -> `Indexes and tables` -> `Index entry` (make sure to select `Table of Contents` as index type). This way, the index entries will appear in a ToC created inside LO Writer, but not as PDF bookmarks. Maybe this is due to a [bug that's more than one year old](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=73295)... :-(

Comment: I've [filed a bug report](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90495) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by moving Title style into Paragraph 1, Paragraph 1 into Paragraph 2, and so on. Those are enlisted in the TOC within the pdf.